# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'match') error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I had this code snippet working for a long time and since upgrading to `v17` of node I'm getting:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'match')
```

Here is the code I'm executing:

```js
// -- string.js
var query = process.argv[2];
const re = /(IN|SC|ABC|QZA|DEV)\d{6,8}$/i;
const type = query.match(re)[1].toUpperCase();
```

I run this from a shell script so there is no `package.json`. I have read about ESCM modules and wondering whether this is because of that and how  to fix this. Not a node guru so please excuse if this has been asked in a different form before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node.js version 17 is not yet stable. You shouldn't be using it unless you really know what you are doing. You will run into problems, for example when using third-party packages and so on. The latest stable version is `16.17.0` as mentioned on Node.js's official [website](https://nodejs.org/en/).